# Generate valid PDF/X-1a file with ConTeXt

Tags: context, pdfx

I want to generate a valid PDF/X-1a file with ConTeXt. I'm currently doing

```tex
\setupbackend[
    format=PDF/X-1a:2001,
    intent={Coated FOGRA39 (ISO 12647-2:2004)}]
```

When I validate the resulting PDF in Acrobat however, I get lots of errors. Here's the first three:

```
            Object uses RGB
                Is DeviceRGB
                Outside visible page area
                Detailed information
                    Graphic state properties
                        Graphic properties
                            Current transformation matrix (CTM)
                                1.000000
                                0.000000
                                0.000000
                                1.000000
                                0.000000
                                267.986786
                                X translation: 0.000000
                                Y translation: 267.986786
                                X scaling: 1.000000
                                Y scaling: 1.000000
                                Rotation counterclockwise: 0.000000
                                Skew: 0.000000
                            Effective line width: 0.398500
                            Miter limit: 10.000000
                            Stroke adjustment: False
                            Flatness: 1.000000
                            Smoothness: 0.000000
                            Overprint mode: 0
                            Overprint for stroke: False
                            Overprint for fill: False
                            Rendering intent: RelativeColorimetric
                            Line dash pattern
                                Dash phase: 0.000000
                            Line cap style: Butt end caps
                            Line join style: Miter joins
                            Fill color space
                                DeviceRGB color space
                            Fill colorant values
                                0.137000
                                0.122000
                                0.125000
                            Stroke color space
                                DeviceGray color space
                            Transparency
                                Fill constant alpha: 1.000000
                                Stroke constant alpha: 1.000000
                                Alpha is shape: False
                                Text knockout: True
            Object uses RGB
                Is DeviceRGB
                Detailed information
                    Graphic state properties
                        Images
                            Current transformation matrix (CTM)
                                170.348892
                                0.000000
                                0.000000
                                257.952698
                                6.952600
                                8.505585
                                X translation: 0.040814
                                Y translation: 0.032973
                                X scaling: 170.348892
                                Y scaling: 257.952698
                                Rotation counterclockwise: 0.000000
                                Skew: 0.000000
                            Current position and size
                                X position on page (pt): 6.952600
                                Y position on page (pt): 8.505585
                                Width on page (pt): 170.348892
                                Height on page (pt): 257.952698
                            Current image resolution
                                Horizontal resolution (pixels/inch): 978.039795
                                Vertical resolution (pixels/inch): 978.039795
                            Width: 2314
                            Height: 3504
                            Bits per color component: 8
                            Treated as a mask: False
                            Perform interpolation: False
                            Rendering intent: RelativeColorimetric
                            Compression/encoding
                                ZIP/Flate compression: FlateDecode
                            DeviceRGB color space
            Object uses RGB
                Is DeviceRGB
                Detailed information
                    Graphic state properties
                        Graphic properties
                            Current transformation matrix (CTM)
                                1.000000
                                0.000000
                                0.000000
                                1.000000
                                0.000000
                                0.000002
                                X translation: 0.000000
                                Y translation: 0.000002
                                X scaling: 1.000000
                                Y scaling: 1.000000
                                Rotation counterclockwise: 0.000000
                                Skew: 0.000000
                            Effective line width: 0.398500
                            Miter limit: 10.000000
                            Stroke adjustment: False
                            Flatness: 1.000000
                            Smoothness: 0.000000
                            Overprint mode: 0
                            Overprint for stroke: False
                            Overprint for fill: False
                            Rendering intent: RelativeColorimetric
                            Line dash pattern
                                Dash phase: 0.000000
                            Line cap style: Butt end caps
                            Line join style: Miter joins
                            Fill color space
                                DeviceRGB color space
                            Fill colorant values
                                0.000000
                                0.000000
                                0.000000
                            Stroke color space
                                DeviceGray color space
                        Text properties
                            Type 0 font
                                PostScript name: NewG8-Bol
                                Unicode CMap is present
                                Encoding: Identity-H
                                Font is a subset
                                Descendant fonts
                                    CID Type 0 font
                                        CID font system info
                                            Issuer (Registry): "Adobe"
                                            Unique name (Ordering): "Identity"
                                            Supplement number (Supplement): 0
                                        Embedded: True
                                        Font descriptors
                                            Maximum height above the baseline: 777
                                            y-coordinate of the top of flat capital letters: 696
                                            Maximum depth below the baseline: -223
                                            Italic angle in degrees counterclockwise: 0
                                            Width of the dominant vertical stems of glyphs: 92
                                            Average width of characters: 0
                                            Desired spacing between lines: 0
                                            Maximum width of characters: 0
                                            Width to use for un-encoded characters.: 0
                                            Vertical width of the dominant horizontal stems of glyphs: 0
                                            y-coordinate of the top of flat non-ascending lowercase letters: 439
                                            PostScript name: TWTZWX+NewG8-Bol
                                            Various properties
                                                Fixed-width font: False
                                                Serif font: False
                                                Symbolic font: True
                                                Script font: False
                                                Uses the Adobe Standard Roman Character Set: False
                                                Italic: False
                                                All-caps font: False
                                                Small-caps font: False
                                                Force bold at small text sizes: False
                            Current font size: 8.368596
                            Transparency
                                Fill constant alpha: 1.000000
                                Stroke constant alpha: 1.000000
                                Alpha is shape: False
                                Text knockout: True
```

So from what I understand, both the included images and the text use RGB colors. That seems strange as I specifically defined the target color space, shouldn't that encode the colors properly? Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: According to [contextgarden](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/PDFX) you have to convert your images in order to use PDF/X-1: "PDF/X-1 uses device dependent colors, i.e. your pictures must be converted into the output color space (gray or CMYK)."

Comment: @DG' Okay that sounds reasonable. What about the text color though?

Comment: I think you might have more luck with this question on the ConTeXt mailing list. (I have no way to do the validation.)

Comment: @flyx -- PDF/X-1 is very restrictive (and old) but if you absolutely must use it, you could try to redefine the colors in cmyk. Also: As mickep already said, try the mailing list

Comment: @DG' Yeah sadly my print shop requires this format, I'll have a go at the mailing list, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless ConTeXt has a graphics capability that re-composes your images from RGB to CMYK, you will have to do it yourself. This is easily done with ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick. Also, for PDF/X-1a:2001, the images must be stripped of metadata (such as EXIF) and not have a color profile attached.

Scripts (BASH) for doing this, and useful color profiles, are in the "extras" directory of the `novel` class documentation. They can be used with any document class or TeX compiler, because they are BASH (or Windows) scripts.

But since you have Acrobat DC, why not let that program do it for you? Not sure if you would need a "Pro" version. It can process the images, add or subtract metadata, and so forth.

Comment: I don't have Acrobat DC, a friend has it on their work PC – the free version cannot even validate. I'd like to have a general solution for future projects without bothering them every time. While transforming the images seems simple enough, I'm unsure about how to make the text not RGB. Do I need to redefine „black“ as CMYK?

Comment: @flyx I doubt if you need to redefine black as CMYK, but I do not use ConTeXt. Do you have any vector images (TiKz,  etc.)? If so, convert them to raster PNG, and use the PNG (in black/white, grayscale, or CMYK). It may be the case that some packages automatically provide RGB "whether you like it or not".

Comment: @flyx In fact, NEVER define text as RGB or CMYK, unless it is actually colored text. This is generally true, not just in your case. Also: In the output you posted, "outside visible page area" means that something (text or image) is protruding beyond the PDF crop box (you would call it the paper size).

Comment: I do use TikZ, but mostly for arranging text – I don't really draw anything apart from a few lines. If text piped through TikZ is the source of the problem, I will need a completely different setup as converting the pictures to png is not viable for this document. I have seen the „outside visible page area“ but since it's nested below „Object uses RGB“ I read it as mere information rather than a separate error.

Comment: Do you have software that can decompress the PDF? I believe the command-line `qpdf` can do it. Then look at the decompressed PDF in a text editor. Find `RGB` and see what it refers to. Often, the problem object will not itself say RGB, but will refer to a colorspace RGB somewhere else in the file. Also: I doubt if colored text is the problem.